# SwiftUI - How to apply aspectFit to image so it does not go outside of designated area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to fit a square shaped image in rectangle shaped ImageView. With storyboard, I can easily do it with content mode .aspectFit but I am unable to figure out how to do it with SwiftUI.

I am currently doing something like this:

```
    Image("BG")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .scaledToFill()
        .clipped()
        .frame(height: 200)
```

which gives below output, notice the blue border is my actual ImageView:

[image]

However, I am expecting something like this which I did in storyboard:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clip it after set size, like

```
Image("BG")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(height: 200)
    .clipped()               // << here !!
```